# Is it best practice to do a new GET request after making a POST request (using React)?

Tags: reactjs, post, get, rest

I'm currently working with React where I'm doing quite a lot of GET & POST requests to an API. If I made a POST request which would add information to the page (for example posting a new article), is it best practice to then do a new GET request following this, to see the changes reflected straight away on the page? Or is it better to store this newly added information in state, rather than doing a new GET request.
Thank you in advance for any help/clarification.

Comment: If the post request is successful then updating the DOM is faster than fetching the entire list. But it also depends on how the app or that component should behave etc.

Comment: Also, often when you do a post request to a API it returns the new data. So you would not need to do another get request.