# Return new data after POST request Best Practice

Tags: c#, reactjs

TL;DR: What's best practice to update users list in Client App after a request changes the list?

Currently I am creating a full stack app and as of right now, it only has registration/log in and an admin section that adds roles to the app and manages the users.

In my React app, currently, I make a request to the API to add a new user as the admin or change an existing user's name etc. I perform the request, send some data (about the new user or what should be changed) and receive a new list with the users, which I set in the component's state that re-renders the page with the new data.

In the API controller, I receive that data, perform some checks and if all is ok, create/update the user and query the DB for the user list and return it to the client. All in the same controller method.

My supervisor told me that's a bad idea and should make sure a controller method should only do 1 thing (SOLID) and find a different way to do this. I want to make sure that after any operation interacting with the DB, the page gets updated with the changes. I've checked [Get request after Post request best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142518/is-it-best-practice-to-do-a-new-get-request-after-making-a-post-request-using-r) and I didn't find my answer there.

Some code samples:

```
// calling the user creation method
export const createUser = (user, onSucceed, onFail) => {
    axios.post("api/users/creation", {
            "firstName": user.firstName,
            "lastName": user.lastName,
            "email": user.email,
            "password": user.password,
            "roles": user.role
        })
        .then((response) => {
            // onSucceed simply performs a few minor
            // tasks for antd Table component and sets the state
            // with the users list
            onSucceed(response);
        })
        .catch((exception) => {
            // shows notification with the error and message of the error
            onFail(exception);
        })
}
```

My controller method:

```
async public Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(CreateUserModel userToCreate)
{
      // some checks for incoming data and other logic

      // TODO: Best practice for updating list 

      // queries the DB and returns the latest list of users
      var userDbList = _userManager.Users.ToList();
      var userReturnList = userDbList.Select(async user => new GetUsersModel
      {
           Name = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}",
           UserName = user.UserName,
           Email = user.Email,
           Roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)
      });

      return Ok(new { Users = userReturnList, Message = AppResources.UserCreated });
}
```

Comment: for create use POST and When you needs to replace an existing Resource entirely, they can use PUT. When they're doing a partial update, they can use PATCH.

Comment: The SOLID principles only apply where they make sense and have clear benefits. Whether your HTTP roundrip does 1, 2 or 3 things internally and/or what it returns depends on your **consumer needs**, not on coding conventions and principles. Imagine in 2 years your code is on prod and you get a call from the head of infra, he asks you why are you *always* doing `GET` after `POST` about 5 000 000 times a day? Let me tell you, "Because SOLID" won't wash with them :). Don't prematurely optimize but also don't induce added penalties just because code style.

Comment: With that said, tailor your API per client needs - think about how it's going to be used and based on that, it could be better to split it up, for reasons that still have nothing to do with SOLID.

Answer (score 0):

There are two standard ways:

**Optimistic way:**

you assume that data which had sent to server would be created or updated certainly, so you update the array in UI immediately if after a while server send an exception you should rollback the updated array.

**Pessimistic way:**

you want to be sure that changes was saved in database, then show to user. so you should just fetch data after create or update data.